# Strange characters for an ellipsis from an RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

I'm using curl and utf8_encode to get the xml from from an rss feed of blog posts from another web site. But when someone puts an ellipsis in their post, I get a weird characterter which, when I view the source code, is %e2%80%a6/

So, my question is what can I do to either eliminate the ellipsis when I present the output or change it into something that works when I present this on my site?  Note, the RSS feed has charset=utf-8 and so does the page where I'm trying to present the feed on my site.

Comment: Please provide some code (how you're parsing the feed). Also, what are you using `utf8_encode` for? You're saying the feed is utf-8 and so is your site. `utf8_encode` encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8. Hence it is not applicable here. As an aside, IMHO, "utf8_encode" is one of the most misleading function names in PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `utf8_encode` text that is already UTF-8 encoded. `utf8_encode` *converts* text from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. Text that is not ISO-8859-1 encoded or that's already UTF-8 encoded will be messed up because of it.

Comment: +1 If I remember correctly, the insight "of mine" above stems from one of your articles...